# How to fix the amount of bandwidth of iperf in tcp mode?

Tags: load-balancing, tcp, bandwidth-control, iperf, bandwidth-measuring

I'm working on some experiments about my master's degree project. I'm studying some load-balancers (**I'm not supposed to cite them here**) and the aim is to get for each bandwidth the cpu % usage of a load-balncer x.

I'm using iperf to send traffic to these load-balancers in TCP mode but I can not control the bandwidth of iperf in TCP mode, I can not use UDP mode because the said load-balancers does not handle UDP traffic.

I tried using **wondershaper tool** and **tc command** but I'm getting strange results and the results do not make sense.

I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction to achieve this. Thank you so much.

Is there any possibility to use **Scapy** to forge packets of a fixed amount of bandwidth, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong in this point.

Thank you so much.

Comment: probably iperf is wrong choice. The whole purpose of iperf is to find maximum achievable speed between two hosts. Why can't you use rsync/wget to transfer some data because they have built-in option which allows you to throttle bandwidth. if you have more questions about how to do it, RTFM ;)

Comment: Probably yes. By the way, maybe the right direction is to look for workload/traffic generator for my evaluation @ Nehal Dattani.